# RoR: Test for duplicate users failings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following along Michael Hartl's excellent RailsTutorial and got stuck in the middle of the book with this validation for duplicate users.

I found some suggestions on the web but none works for my code.

app/models/user.rb

```
ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
end
```

test/models/user_test.rb

```
.
.
.
 test "email addresses should be unique" do
     duplicate_user = @user.dup
     duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
     @user.save
     assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
   end
```

The test only passes if I comment out this test line:

```
duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
```

With this code I get the following FAIL message:

```
FAIL["test_email_addresses_should_be_unique", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f8586cf6b98 @name="UserTest">, 0.044708000001264736]
 test_email_addresses_should_be_unique#UserTest (0.04s)
        Expected true to be nil or false
        test/models/user_test.rb:49:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

Changing the user Class with

```
before_save { email.downcase! }
```

to

```
{ self.email = email.downcase }
```

or

```
before_save { email.downcase! }
```

doesn't work. Only uncommenting this line works:

```
duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm missing are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `before_save` happens after the validation and therefore `@user.email` and `duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase` are still different when the model is validated.

Just change the `before_save` callback to:

```
before_validation { email.downcase! }
```

Have a look at the [list of available callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) and the order in which they are called in the Rails Guides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:case_sensitive`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) option. By default it's `true`. But you can customize it.

```
uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

So it will be

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  before_save { email.downcase! }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```